# Cannot read property 'on' of undefined? -> ERROR

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

So I'm creating a web app and while building the server part I got stuck because of an error in the CMD that says:

```
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
```

I tried to make the connection between the server.js and client.js but it seems not to work even though I've included all the needed modules.

```
var fs = require('fs'); // required for file serving
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var socket = require('socket.io');
var io = require('socket.io');

// loading all HTMl files

// loading CSS, JS, Pictues

//  for the HTML index 

// server.listen

//  !!! HERE IS THE PROBLEM !!!
 io.sockets.on('connection', newConnection);
 function newConnection(socket){
    console.log('new connection');
    console.log(socket);
 }
```

I want my server.js to contact with the client.js (there's nothing written in it) and run as a normal server!

Every advice is much appreciated! :)

Comment: `io.sockets` is `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass your server object to the io initializer. The following code might help:

```
var fs = require('fs'); // required for file serving
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
server.listen(port);

io.sockets.on('connection', newConnection);
function newConnection(socket){
   console.log('new connection');
   console.log(socket);
}
```

Comment: Tried it , and it worked the only issue is that it doesn't do the console.log('new connection');,   How can I do the client part, any ideas?

Comment: In the client side use:
`<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
var socket = io.connect();
</script>
`

Answer (score 1):

You initialized `io` incorrectly. Try like this:

```
var io = socket(http);
```

Answer (score 0):

Only One **require** statement is required.Remove one of them.

like

```
const io=require("socket.io");

io.on("conn",function(){
        console.log("New Connection");
})
```

Comment: But the `io` object is still not initialized. You still need to pass it the `server` object so it can listen to it.

Comment: Thanks for your advice